# How to loop through 2D matrices of a 4D (None, x, y, z) activation tensor from a resnet layer?

Tags: keras, keras-layer, activation, resnet

I wanna loop through 2D matrices of a 4D tensor which is the output of a resnet layer (activation map or feature map) in order to modify it a bit at test time

NB: am using keras

I tried converting the tensor to a numpy array using different codes and i am getting some weird errors

To summarize: i just need to apply some modification to the activation tensor of a resnet layer and then continue the forward pass in order to "maybe" get some accuracy enhancement

Answer (score 0):

You can use [keras.backend.function](https://keras.io/backend/#function). Since you haven't provided the model structure I will use the following model whose output is 4D tensor.

```py
model = Sequential(
   [
      Conv2D(z, 3, input_shape=(x, y, 3), padding="same"),
   ]
);

print(model.output.shape) # None, x, y, z)
```

With this model, one can use [`keras.backend.function`](https://keras.io/backend/#function) function to get output values at specific location. In your case you are trying to get last 2 dimensions, so you have to index using batch index and width index(assuming channels_last data format).

```py
def get_model_output_at(model, batch_index, width_index):
    output = model.output[batch_index][width_index]
    return keras.backend.function(model.input, output)
```

Now you can use this function to get 2D tensors using specific indexing.

```py
func = get_model_output_at(model, 0, 0) # To access the first row of the first image(batch 0 and row 0).
images = np.random.randn(10, x, y, z) # Random images
output = func(images)
print(output.shape)  # (y, z)
```

#### EDIT

To loop over the feature map, use the following function

```py
def get_feature_map_at(model, index):
    output = model.output[:, :, :, index]
    return keras.backend.function(model.input, output)
```

Now using the above function you can loop through each feature map.

```py
image = np.random.randn(1, 55, 55, 256) 
for i in range(model.output.shape[-1]):
     feature_map_i_function = get_feature_map_at(model, i)
     feature_map_i = feature_map_i_function(image).reshape(55, 55)
```

There is actually better way to achieve the above task using model.predict and looping over the result array.

```py
image = np.random.randn(1, 55, 55, 256) 
predicted_feature_map = model.predict(image)
for i in range(predicted_feature_map.shape[-1]):
    feature_map_i = predicted_feature_map[:, :, :, i].reshape(55,55)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response am currently at test time with a batch size of one and i need to get the 2D matrix of the activations of each image for instance after my first block i've got a tensor of shape (1, 55, 55, 256) and i need to loop trough all 256 matrices of this tensor i don't have a problem on extracting it as i am adding my processing block to the pretrained model itself so i have it's outputs

Comment: Thank you so much fo your reply but i think you didn't get my point the problem is that i don't have a model i am trying to tweek it a bit i can't call it while modifying it at the same time am working inside the architecture of my model trying to take it's intermediate output and process them than forward this processed tensor to the next layer etc. i'am facing a problem on how to take these intermediate activations and loop over them and then forward this processed activation to the next layer

Comment: Which means i can't call it with model.predict() i am modifying it's architecture and when i am trying to catch it's intermediate outputs i am not able to process them

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i think i get it i will cut resnet into two models and predict on the first model then preprocess this predicted activations and make it as an input to the second model, but untill now i am getting an error on the creation of the seconf model as its input is as follow: resnet.get_layer('layerName').input